# How to install an application on an Android phone?

Tags: android

I create an android application. I need the check, how my application is working on the device. How to install the application on the android device ?

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways by which you can install a **.apk** file into your phone.

- If you are a developer, you can just push the .apk to the phone by connecting the device to the Workstation, and enabling *USB Debugging*.
- You can put the *.apk* in a website and enter the URL in the mobile browser [But may involve airtime charges]
- You can copy the *.apk* to your SD Card and use third party APK-installers from Android market to install it.
- The **best way** I would recommend is to copy the *.apk* to you SD Card and then from the mobile browser just type *file:///sdcard/[yourapp].apk* and it will automatically call the Package Manager to install the *.apk*.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways.

You could export an APK-file and install it, for instance by putting it on the web and point you browser to the APK file.

The page at http://help.codesector.com/ApkInstall suggests that you use the AppsInstaller application.

This page, http://www.technipages.com/htc-droid-incredible-install-apk-files.html, suggests Astro File Manager, and lists the steps involved.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://d.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) from the Android developer website will help you. Basically, once you plug in your phone (and have enabled USB debugging in its settings), when "running" an application from Eclipse a dialog will appear where you'll be able to choose your device. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out you can email the apk to your gmail account as an attatchment and you can install the apk straight from the email. When you open up the email scroll to the very botton and you will see a "Install" button.  it's a quick and easy solution.  It's a great solution too if you want to share your applications with friends for QA.